# How to make Honey Roasted Peanuts just like Planters?

Tags: roasting, honey, peanuts

I tried to make honey roasted peanuts looking at some blogs. 
But I didn't come out so well. It was not very crisp and sticking with other peanuts definitely not like what you get from store.

Any help. Truly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a more complete recipe? Maybe a link to a blog?

Answer (score 2):

The best *first* resource and guideline for replicating specific commercial products is always the nutritional fact information on the back of the package.

http://planters.com/varieties/nutrition-information.aspx?Site=1&Product=2900007345

Ingredients:  Peanuts, ***sugar***, honey, oils, corn syrup, salt, fructose, & stuff.

The lesson, here, is that Planters Dry Roasted Honey Roasted Peanuts (two roasted-s?) are actually ***sugar***-honey roasted.  Most honey-roasted nut recipes swap butter for the oil (I think that would be a desirable swap!) - but if you're looking for that Planters flavor, you're going to need to make sure your recipe calls for more sugar than honey.

Getting heavy-handed and sloppy with the honey is going to take you in the direction of some failed foray into honey peanut brittle territory - you're looking for a delicate flavoring touch here so be delicate with the ingredients.

Also, for what it's worth, please note that the Planters information would imply that their peanuts are made with no flavorings or spices.  Evaluate your recipe accordingly.

Comment: They call it honey roasted but really, it should be "caramelized and then we accidentally drop a bit of honey on it"